# Capture network requests like in Chrome DevTools

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently studying selenium. I need to capture all network requests in order to see them like in Chrome DevTools. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Chrome_DevTools]

`RequestIntercepted` event doesn't help

I've been trying to find a solution for the past few days and nothing. I would also appreciate any advice from other libraries.

What I need: execute some commands or scripts like in selenium, intercept network requests.

My code:

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V107.Network
Public Class SeleniumTest
    Private Driver As OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver
    Private Session As OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.DevToolsSession
    Private WithEvents Network As OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V107.Network.NetworkAdapter
    Public Async Sub Load(Url As String)
        Driver = New ChromeDriver(New ChromeOptions)
        Dim DevTools As IDevTools = Driver
        Session = DevTools.GetDevToolsSession()
        Network = Session.GetVersionSpecificDomains(Of OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V107.DevToolsSessionDomains).Network
        Await Network.Enable(New EnableCommandSettings())
        Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(Url)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Click()
        Try
            Dim elem As IWebElement = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("video-holder"))
            elem.Click()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Network_ResponseReceived(sender As Object, e As ResponseReceivedEventArgs) Handles Network.ResponseReceived
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Response.Url)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works without any additional libraries with Selenium 4.6 and .NET 6 on Win10

```
using System;
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V107.DevToolsSessionDomains;
using Network = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V107.Network;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;

namespace Selenium$id {

    public class SeleniumTest  {

[STAThread]
        public void Start() {
            string url = "https://www.google.de/";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            var driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\martin\\git\\libraries\\selenium\\");
            var devTools = (OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.IDevTools)driver;
            OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
            var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
            domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = domains.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
            task.Wait();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(uri);
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            driver.Dispose();

            void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, Network.ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url }");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to capture the network calls via selenium.
I'm currently using `Selenium 4.6.0` and `.NET 7`.

You need to enable network from a devtools session and to subscribe to `DevToolsEventReceived` :

```
const string Url = @"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419089/capture-network-requests-like-in-chrome-devtools";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();

IDevTools devTools = driver;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
await session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();
session.DevToolsEventReceived += OnReceive;

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

void OnReceive(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventName == EventName.responseReceived.ToString())
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.EventData);
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }    
}

// Just for demo purposes, in a real world app you might want to await 
// here in order to not stop the execution
Console.ReadLine();

// This is a custom `enum` to help you choose the appropriate event name
public enum EventName
{
    requestWillBeSentExtraInfo,
    requestWillBeSent,
    responseReceivedExtraInfo,
    responseReceived,
    attachedToTarget,   
    detachedFromTarget
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't work. I used the same event handler but from `NetworkAdapter` (`NetworkAdapter.ResponseReceived`) because your handler provides `NewtonSoft.JToken` stuff which doesn't even convert `ToString`. Even when I installed the NewtonSoft NuGet package, I cannot use the `e.EventData` property. I don't know why. Besides, I'm assuming that this handler stopped after a while because I don't see some events after a while when I need to see it.

Comment: You mean that you just can't convert response to string, not that it doesn't return a response (JToken) at all right? Because i run it without problems

Comment: Check the updated code, i converted the jtoken to string

Comment: Or if you can't use the above code, share what you have tried so far in order to help you. Also if you use selenium only for capturing network calls consider to use `Titanium Web Proxy` ( https://github.com/justcoding121/titanium-web-proxy) .

Comment: I have added the code to the original message. No, I got an error when trying to use `e.EventData`: `Public Overloads Property OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs.EventData As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is not accessible in this context because the return type is not accessible.`.

Comment: I just tried using 'Titanium' and it works like a charm! Many thanks for this suggestion. I'll definitely use it. But it monitors requests of any browser. And that's not exactly what I'm looking for right now. So my question about Selenium is still in order.